# pass string as argument in fuction from getline

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file line by  line and then put in variables each word of the line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>
#include "record.h"
using namespace std;

void handleline(string& line1, int a)
{
    //cout<<line1[]<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    string line1[30];
    ifstream myfile("30+.in");
    int a = 0;
    if (!myfile) {
        cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;

        return -1;
    }
    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        getline(myfile, line1[a], '\n');

        handleline(line1, a);
    }
}
```

the problem is that i cant pass the line as argument  in to the function.

any help will be appreciated !

Comment: One reason why the code does not work is that your handleline function takes as the first argument a string&, but you called it with a string*. Type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
void handleline(string & line)
{
    //you have just the one line to work on in this implementation
}

...

while (!myfile.eof()) {
    getline(myfile, line1[a], '\n');

    handleline(line1[a]);

    a++; // you forgot to increment a in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string line1[30];
```

defines an array of `string`.

```
handleline(line1, a);
```

passes that array of `string` into `handleline`. `line1` will decay ([What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)) into a pointer to `string`, a `string *`. Unfortunately

```
void handleline(string& line1, int a)
```

expects a reference to a `string`. A single `string`, not an array of `string` or a pointer to `string`.

Since `handleline` only consumes a single `string` at a time

```
void handleline(string& line)
{
    //cout<<line<<"\n";
}
```

seems more reasonable.

It would be called with

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<string> line1; // replaced array with resizable array to prevent overflow
    ifstream myfile("30+.in");
    int a = 0;
    if (!myfile) {
        cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;

        return -1;
    }
    string temp; // declares a temporary holder
    while (getline(myfile, temp, '\n')) // reads file into holder. Note this replaces 
                                         // !myfile.eof(), which is a classic bug. 
                                         // More on that later.
    {
        handleline(temp); // consume the one string
        line1.push_back(temp); // store in resizable array if needed.
    }
}
```

[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)